# Raster package, substitute

Tags: r, raster, na, substitution, r-raster

I'm trying to reclassify a `RasterLayer` to turn all 0's to NA. I've tried:

1. Reclassify:

   ```
   con1RC<-reclassify(con2, matrix(c(0, 0, NA))
   ```

   ERROR: cannot allocate vector of size 160.1 Mb
2. Subs:

   ```
    con1Sub<-subs(con2, df, by=1, which=2)
   ```

   ERROR:
   error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix'
3. Replace NA:

   ```
   con1Sub<-con2[is.na(con2)]<-0'
   ```

   ERROR: cannot allocate vector of size 160.1 Mb

```
    con2
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 5533, 3792, 20981136  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 242505, 356265, 4234635, 4400625  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=18 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : G:\Projects\DC\Imagery\Landsat\Classification\Working\confused2_rc_8class.img 
names       : confused2_rc_8class 
values      : 0, 8  (min, max)
```

I'm using R3.0.0. Windows 7 enterprise, 32 bit. I know memory can be an issue but haven't seen any direction on how to change in windows. I've also used in this code:

```
memory.size(max=FALSE)
memory.limit(size=NA)
```

I'll try these on a 64-bit computer too.

Anyone know what's happening with this machine, or can recommend a way to get one of these functions to work?
I'm not calling any matrix with method 2 (just a `data.frame`), so not sure what this means either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
matrix(c(0, 0, NA))
```

instead, try

```
con1RC<-reclassify(con2, cbind(0, NA) )
```

If you still get out of memory problems, first set some options:

```
rasterOptions(chunksize=1e+06, maxmemory=1e+07)
```

Comment: Thank you roberth. I've learned a lot more about memory allocation and now use the rasterTmpFile() command with each function to write to our working drive.